# How to update stdout coming from internal command?

Tags: bash

I've a bash script which uses internal script and internal script is interactive in nature.

Sample Output :

```
Speed: 1MB/S File_in_process: xyz.tar
Files extracted: file1, file2... fileN
...
...
Task completed successfully. 
# wrapper script operation
headers updated of file(1-N)
Script completed successfully.
```

I need help in either to remove `Task completed successfully.` or update with `ABC Task completed successfully`, because it is very misleading and getting two success messages. I'm trying with `/dev/null` and `awk` but no luck in changing only a single line. Please share some ideas.

Comment: It's been a while since I did it in bash but you can pipe ALL STDOUT from a command to another function (using a for loop) and determine which lines you want to re-echo or not within that function.  As @dodrg points out in his posted answer, without your script or at least the portions that matter.. all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 2):

A hint: You really should provide some sample code so we can reproduce the problem and see the details.

The first thing would be to check the man page of the `ABC Task` for an option to switch it to silent or batch mode.

If there is no option then the output can be sent to `/dev/null`. You mentioned this option already in your question and didn't succeed. So I suppose you didn't test weather the output goes to `stdout` or to `stderr`. Being a status message *"ABC Task completed successfully"* probably goes to `stderr`.

```sh
# Send all output to /dev/null:
ABC_Task  >/dev/null 2>&1

# or only the "stderr", so regular operation output is displayed:
ABC_Task  2>/dev/null

# Then check for the exit code to decide the next action.
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "failure"
fi
```

The same slightly shorter, but not such obvious:

```sh
if ABC_Task  >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "failure"
fi
```

Comment: `if $(ABC_Task  >/dev/null 2>&1); then` tries to execute the null output of `ABC_Task` as a command. Instead, use `if ABC_Task >/dev/null 2>&1; then` (i.e. without the `$( … )` construct)

Comment: Well, somehow the "meaningless op" has a value of truth that changes due to the success of the executed `ABC_Task`. — But your option works too and is simpler so better. I update.

Comment: It does indeed have state that changes according to the exit status. But it's wrong in that it executes the (null) output of the command. The general structure `if $( command )` is inherently incorrect and should only be `if command` without the `$( … )` part

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it and test the next days (a bit late for now).

Comment: Did this solve your question? Or is there something open?